# How to find out if an element has an function attached or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

There is a lot of these questions, but I just can't make it work. I have a page where some of the elements have a jQuery elements attached to it, and some dont. How can I check if an element have a function attached and how can I attach a function to the elements that does not already have function attached (this happens because some of the elements are loaded dynamically with endless page scroll)?

I want to attach this function to the elements that does not have a function already attached:

```
 $ ->
  $(".like_button").click (e) ->
     #Code for liking here
```

Comment: If you are dynamicly addibng elements, use [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this mundane exercise, you could bind the `click` (or any event handler) to the  closest static parent use event delegation for your actions :

```
$(document).on 'click', '.like_button', -> // or closest static parent
   #Code for liking here
```

This will also work for dynamic elements. for more info, [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Wow, the .on function was really helpfull. Thanks!